# How to add a class name to an input on a SimpleSchema AutoForm in react?

Tags: reactjs, antd, uniform, simpl-schema

I want to add a class name for an individual input, but I could not find anything on the docs about a class name property for simpl-schema or uniforms-bridge-simple-schema-2.

```
import { AutoForm } from "uniforms-antd";
import SimpleSchemaBridge from "uniforms-bridge-simple-schema-2";
import SimpleSchema from "simpl-schema";

const rawSchema = {
    name: {
      type: String,
      optional: true,
      // className - how to add a class name for an individual input?
    }
};

const schema = new SimpleSchemaBridge(new SimpleSchema(rawSchema));

return (
    <AutoForm
        schema={schema}
        model={model ? model : {}}
        onSubmit={(values: any) => {
        onUpdate(values);
        }}
    />
);
```

Comment: could you create a code sandbox?

Comment: Hi! Yes, here: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-night-l0hxu

Answer (score 0):

I have not explored all the APIs of `uniforms`. I found this way you can add `classNames` to each field.

Their [FAQ](https://uniforms.tools/docs/faq/#how-can-i-customizestyle-my-form-fields) says :

> How can I customize/style my form fields?
>   You can style your form
>   fields simply by passing a className property.

[image: uniforms-antd-textfield]

**App**

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { AutoForm, AutoField, SubmitField, ErrorsField } from "uniforms-antd";
import SimpleSchemaBridge from "uniforms-bridge-simple-schema-2";
import SimpleSchema from "simpl-schema";

export default function App() {
  const rawSchema = {
    name: {
      type: String,
      optional: false,
      //className: 'test'// - not working
      // className - how to add a class name for an individual input?
    } 
  };
  const schema = new SimpleSchemaBridge(new SimpleSchema(rawSchema));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AutoForm schema={schema} >

      <AutoField name="name" className="test"/>
      <ErrorsField className="my-error"/>
      <SubmitField className="my-submit"/>

      </AutoForm>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**css**

```
.test{
  border: 1px solid navy;
  border-radius: 12px;
  height: 45px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.my-error{ 
}

.my-submit{
}
```

Notes:

1) Check out all the fields of [uniforms-antd](https://github.com/vazco/uniforms/tree/master/packages/uniforms-antd/src).

2) [Customizing your form layout](https://uniforms.tools/docs/tutorials-customizing-your-form-layout)